# YAML formatting error in cloudformation. How do i fix this error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a YAML based template for cloudformation but i need to fix this error that does not allow the template to work on aws. When put in a yaml validator, it works, but aws is currently not accepting this:

```
Properties:
  Code:
    Zipfile:|
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get bucket name from the S3 event
    print(event)

    bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

    # Create a bucket policy
    bucket_policy =json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                        "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                          -----
                            "aws:kms"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                        "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                        }
                }
            } ] })


    # Set the new policy
    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy),

  Handler: lambda_handler,
  Role: -----
  Runtime: python3.7

Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
  EventPattern:  {
                    "source": [
                        "aws.s3"
                    ],
                    "detail-type": [
                        "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
                    ],
                    "detail": {
                        "eventSource": [
                            "s3.amazonaws.com"
                        ],
                        "eventName": [
                            "CreateBucket"
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

What do i do to fix this?
I have tried putting it in the yaml validator yet the error message points to line 1 column 1, and i have followed aws documentation fully but something seems to be wrong. Does everything need to be in a string like it is in JSON format?

Comment: for formatting you can use the cloud formation designer. upload your yaml in cloud formation designer and check its graph and dependecies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have 2 resources in this template without naming separate resources. I have formatted for you below.

There were a couple of issues with the YAML, the first is alignment of the structure, whereas in JSON `{}` and `[]` define nested levels in YAML indentation combined with `:` is used to provide structure.

With the Lambda if you keep it indented from the ZipFile parameter it will successfully be allowed in the formatting. Additionally the EventPattern within your CloudWatch Event cannot use JSON, it must instead convert the format to YAML for this template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3

          s3 = boto3.client('s3')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            # Get bucket name from the S3 event
            print(event)

            bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

            # Create a bucket policy
            bucket_policy =json.dumps({
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        -----
                        "aws:kms"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:*",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                      "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                      }
                  }
                } ] })


            # Set the new policy
            s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy),
      Handler: lambda_handler
      Role: '-----'
      Runtime: python3.7
  EventRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - CreateBucket
```

Comment: So this works perfectly, but i pasted in my condition server side encryption part that i hyphened out as well as my role because of security, and now im getting a ton of errors and im not sure how this spacing works

Comment: Try to use either 2 spaces or 4 spaces per nested level, but keep it consistent.

Comment: So now that my yaml is valid the new error tells me atleast one resource member should be defined. Arent they written in ```"Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                  "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)``` however?

Comment: This is a Resources section in CloudFormation template, have update above to make it more obvious :)

Comment: creating the stack causes a rollback in which the event tells me it failed to create a lambda function, "encountered unsupported property Zipfile", then after removing zipfile from the code i get "value of property code must be an object" should i create a new thread?

Comment: Apologies that should be `ZipFile`, I had formatted the code you gave me but not actually tested it :)

Comment: now i get the error "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 56597e7a-b8ea-4ecd-82e3-42184479af3f)", "Resource creation cancelled" and "The following resource(s) failed to create: [LambdaFunction, EventRule]. . Rollback requested by user." sorry this is so persistent on not working

Comment: Thats fine, thats related to the IAM role. you must include an AssumeRoleDocument: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument. This must grant access to `lambda.amazonaws.com`. Theres an example at the bottom of that page.